# SwiftUI custom font - all font types use new font

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm currently using a custom font in my app, but am finding it a bit frustrating having to use `.font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 16))` everywhere. Is there a way I can set the the entire app to be using this font, and I can simply use `.font(.system(size: 16))` and even use standard sizes like `.font(.caption)` and it will use the custom font?

I've actually set `.font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 16))` on my ContentView as shown below, which allows me to use this font everywhere, but the size is always 16, and when I change it, the font goes back to the default font.

```
@main
struct AppName: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 16))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create constants using a custom Type, for example `AppFont` like so:

```
enum AppFont {

    static let header       = Font.custom(Raleway.extraBold.weight,    size: 40)
    static let header2      = Font.custom(Raleway.extraBold.weight,    size: 30)
    static let title        = Font.custom(Raleway.bold.weight,         size: 32)
    static let title2       = Font.custom(Raleway.extraBold.weight,    size: 22)
    static let subtitle     = Font.custom(Raleway.bold.weight,         size: 16)
    static let body         = Font.custom(Raleway.medium.weight,       size: 17)
    static let body2        = Font.custom(Raleway.regular.weight,      size: 17)
    static let footnote     = Font.custom(Raleway.regular.weight,      size: 16)
    static let footnote2    = Font.custom(Raleway.regular.weight,      size: 13)
    
    static var custom: (Raleway, CGFloat) -> Font = { (weight, size) in
        return Font.custom(weight.weight, size: size)
    }
}

enum Raleway: String {

    case black        = "Raleway-Black"
    case extraBold    = "Raleway-ExtraBold"
    case bold         = "Raleway-Bold"
    case semiBold     = "Raleway-SemiBold"
    case medium       = "Raleway-Medium"
    case regular      = "Raleway-Regular"
    case light        = "Raleway-Light"
    case extraLight   = "Raleway-ExtraLight"
    case thin         = "Raleway-Thin"
    
    var weight: String { return self.rawValue }
}
```

#### Usage

```
Text("Example")
    .font(AppFont.header)
```

This is an excerpt from my app, you may replace `Raleway` with your font, namely `Montserrat` or any font. Just to give you an example.

#### Note

I would not recommend simply extending `Font`. I find it more clear to have custom Types for any app-custom stuff.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Thanks!